# Cant dynamically add Function

Tags: html, jquery-ui

On my html page I have a table that has dynamically added table rows once a button is clicked. Here is the code behind it. What I am trying to do is add a slider bar to one of the td's. After that I will be taking the value of that slider bar and put it into a cookie. My question is why doesnt this work?

```
$(function(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});

$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
});

$(function () {
                $("#labSlider").slider(
                    {
                        orientation:"horizontal",
                        range:"min",
                        min: 0,
                        max: 25,
                        value: 15,
                        slide: function(event, ui){$("#amount").val(ui.value);}
                    }
                );
                $("#amount").val($("#labSlider").slider("value"));
            });


function labAddRow(){

    var labRows = $('#labTable tr').length;  //how many rows in table
        if (labRows <= 10){
            var newRow = $('<tr><td>' + labRows + '</td><td><div id ="labSlider"></div></td><td><input type="text" class="text_field" maxlength="2" size="2" onchange="calculateGrade()" title= "What did you score on lab '+ labRows+'?"/></td><td>' + "/25" + '</td></tr>');  //create the new row
            $('#labTable').append(newRow);

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a function to `jQuery` causes it to be called when the DOM is ready. It doesn’t execute automatically for DOM changes or anything like that.

Learn to love the DOM! Functions too! You can make a function to create an appropriate slider for an element, then use it whenever you add a row. And I’m not sure what `#amount` is, but it might need to be corrected to match `element`.

```
$(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $(document).tooltip();
});

function createSlider(element) {
    $(element).slider(
        {
            orientation:"horizontal",
            range:"min",
            min: 0,
            max: 25,
            value: 15,
            slide: function(event, ui){$("#amount").val(ui.value);}
        }
    );

    $("#amount").val($(element).slider("value"));
}

function labAddRow() {
    var labRows = $('#labTable tr').length;  //how many rows in table

    if (labRows <= 10) {
        var textField = $('<input>', {
            type: 'text',
            'class': 'text_field',
            maxlength: 2,
            size: 2,
            title: 'What did you score on lab ' + labRows + '?'
        }).on('change', calculateGrade);

        var slider = $('<div>', { id: 'labSlider' });

        var newRow = $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(labRows),
            $('<td>').append(slider),
            $('<td>').append(textField),
            $('<td>', { text: '/25' })
        );

        createSlider(slider);
        $('#labTable').append(newRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: #amount will be used to grab the value of the slider bar in order to enter it into the textbox. I am trying to make it where you can input the value or use the slider to input the value into the textbox.

Comment: also I like what you did up top with the tooltip and tabs function. It looks like you combined them which I didnt know you could do.

Comment: This isnt working out for me. I have even tried adjusting the td fields in the css and I still cant get the slider to properly display and slide.